# Странные падения портов

Tags: свич, администрирование, сеть, подсети

На прошлой неделе начал наблюдать странные падения портов на управляемом свиче d'link dgs-1210-48. (с 1-го по 5-е января (даты такие, так как недавно сбрасывал настройки, время правильное установить не было времени)). Саму сеть физически никто не трогал. Свич подключен через ИБП. Все клиентские ПК тоже подключены через ИБП. Теперь вот сижу в догадках, что это такое могло быть. Лог со свича приведен ниже:

```
 4 Jan 6 01:26:31 2009 Port 47 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 5 Jan 6 00:23:08 2009 Logout through Web( IP: 192.168.0.XXX ) инф. 6 Jan 6 00:23:08 2009 Web session timed out ( IP: 192.168.0.XXX ) инф. 7 Jan 6 00:21:09 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 8 Jan 6 00:20:20 2009 port 16 link down инф. 9 Jan 6 00:15:56 2009 Successful login through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.XXX ) инф. 10 Jan 6 00:12:43 2009 Logout through Web( IP: 192.168.0.XXX ) инф. 11 Jan 6 00:12:43 2009 Web session timed out ( IP: 192.168.0.188 ) инф. 12 Jan 6 00:07:33 2009 Successful login through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.188 ) инф. 13 Jan 5 22:51:03 2009 Port 17 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 14 Jan 5 22:50:44 2009 port 17 link down инф. 15 Jan 5 22:45:45 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 16 Jan 5 22:45:42 2009 port 11 link down инф. 17 Jan 5 22:45:27 2009 Port 11 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 18 Jan 5 21:57:08 2009 Port 8 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 19 Jan 5 21:52:47 2009 Port 19 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 20 Jan 5 21:52:42 2009 port 19 link down инф. 21 Jan 5 21:52:13 2009 Port 19 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 22 Jan 5 21:52:12 2009 port 19 link down инф. 23 Jan 5 21:50:54 2009 port 13 link down инф. 24 Jan 5 21:50:48 2009 Port 19 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 25 Jan 5 21:50:47 2009 Port 27 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 26 Jan 5 21:50:45 2009 port 27 link down инф. 27 Jan 5 21:50:30 2009 Port 28 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 28 Jan 5 21:50:27 2009 port 28 link down инф. 29 Jan 5 21:50:12 2009 Port 27 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 30 Jan 5 21:49:55 2009 Port 28 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 31 Jan 5 21:49:54 2009 port 28 link down инф. 32 Jan 5 21:48:54 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 33 Jan 5 21:42:07 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 34 Jan 5 21:42:05 2009 port 1 link down инф. 35 Jan 5 21:41:38 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 36 Jan 5 21:41:37 2009 port 1 link down инф. 37 Jan 5 21:35:11 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 38 Jan 5 21:34:21 2009 port 16 link down инф. 39 Jan 5 21:30:17 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 40 Jan 5 20:57:16 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 41 Jan 5 20:57:14 2009 port 32 link down инф. 42 Jan 5 20:57:02 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 43 Jan 5 20:56:29 2009 Port 22 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 44 Jan 5 20:56:27 2009 port 22 link down инф. 45 Jan 5 20:56:19 2009 Port 26 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 46 Jan 5 20:56:01 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 47 Jan 5 20:56:00 2009 Port 2 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 48 Jan 5 20:55:59 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 49 Jan 5 20:55:58 2009 port 32 link down инф. 50 Jan 5 20:55:55 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 51 Jan 5 20:55:53 2009 port 32 link down инф. 52 Jan 5 20:55:53 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 53 Jan 5 20:55:51 2009 Port 18 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 54 Jan 5 20:55:49 2009 port 18 link down инф. 55 Jan 5 20:55:44 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 56 Jan 5 20:55:32 2009 Port 18 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 57 Jan 5 20:52:22 2009 Port 33 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 58 Jan 5 20:52:20 2009 port 33 link down инф. 59 Jan 5 20:52:16 2009 Port 33 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 60 Jan 5 20:52:13 2009 port 33 link down инф. 61 Jan 5 20:38:47 2009 Port 21 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 62 Jan 5 20:37:50 2009 port 21 link down инф. 63 Jan 5 20:37:44 2009 Port 21 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 64 Jan 5 20:37:42 2009 port 21 link down инф. 65 Jan 5 20:37:41 2009 Port 21 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 66 Jan 5 20:27:43 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 67 Jan 5 20:27:41 2009 port 1 link down инф. 68 Jan 5 20:27:15 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 69 Jan 5 20:27:13 2009 port 1 link down инф. 70 Jan 5 20:27:12 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 71 Jan 5 20:27:09 2009 port 1 link down инф. 72 Jan 5 20:26:12 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 73 Jan 5 20:02:40 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 74 Jan 5 20:02:37 2009 port 36 link down инф. 75 Jan 5 19:08:04 2009 Port 10 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 76 Jan 5 18:23:29 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 77 Jan 5 03:44:56 2009 port 14 link down инф. 78 Jan 4 20:00:52 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 79 Jan 4 19:59:52 2009 port 14 link down инф. 80 Jan 4 19:59:46 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 81 Jan 4 03:40:34 2009 port 14 link down инф. 82 Jan 3 22:03:14 2009 Port 7 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 83 Jan 3 22:03:12 2009 port 7 link down инф. 84 Jan 3 22:01:32 2009 Port 7 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 85 Jan 3 22:01:30 2009 port 7 link down инф. 86 Jan 3 22:01:04 2009 Port 7 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 87 Jan 3 22:01:02 2009 port 7 link down инф. 88 Jan 3 22:00:29 2009 Port 7 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 89 Jan 3 22:00:28 2009 port 7 link down инф. 90 Jan 3 18:59:06 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 91 Jan 3 11:41:53 2009 port 10 link down инф. 92 Jan 3 11:41:48 2009 port 14 link down инф. 93 Jan 3 11:31:25 2009 port 11 link down инф. 94 Jan 3 07:44:15 2009 port 15 link down инф. 95 Jan 3 07:18:00 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 96 Jan 3 07:17:58 2009 port 11 link down инф. 97 Jan 3 07:17:41 2009 Port 11 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 98 Jan 3 06:56:50 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 99 Jan 3 06:56:45 2009 port 15 link down инф. 100 Jan 3 06:48:19 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 101 Jan 3 06:48:13 2009 port 15 link down инф. 102 Jan 3 06:47:58 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 103 Jan 3 06:47:53 2009 port 15 link down инф. 104 Jan 3 06:47:45 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 105 Jan 3 06:47:40 2009 port 15 link down инф. 106 Jan 3 06:47:39 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 107 Jan 3 06:47:34 2009 port 15 link down инф. 108 Jan 3 06:47:33 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 109 Jan 3 06:22:59 2009 port 13 link down инф. 110 Jan 3 06:22:49 2009 port 11 link down инф. 111 Jan 3 06:22:10 2009 port 19 link down инф. 112 Jan 3 06:21:29 2009 Port 19 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 113 Jan 3 06:21:27 2009 port 19 link down инф. 114 Jan 3 06:19:34 2009 port 18 link down инф. 115 Jan 3 06:17:20 2009 port 8 link down инф. 116 Jan 3 06:15:56 2009 port 20 link down инф. 117 Jan 3 06:15:43 2009 Port 28 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 118 Jan 3 06:15:41 2009 port 28 link down инф. 119 Jan 3 06:15:15 2009 port 22 link down инф. 120 Jan 3 06:15:04 2009 port 2 link down инф. 121 Jan 3 06:14:47 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 122 Jan 3 06:14:45 2009 port 22 link down инф. 123 Jan 3 06:13:23 2009 port 26 link down инф. 124 Jan 3 06:12:58 2009 port 32 link down инф. 125 Jan 3 06:12:50 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 126 Jan 3 06:12:47 2009 port 32 link down инф. 127 Jan 3 06:09:52 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 128 Jan 3 06:04:54 2009 port 15 link down инф. 129 Jan 3 05:49:12 2009 port 1 link down инф. 130 Jan 3 05:48:56 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 131 Jan 3 05:48:54 2009 port 1 link down инф. 132 Jan 3 05:42:24 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 133 Jan 3 05:42:22 2009 port 36 link down инф. 134 Jan 3 05:22:08 2009 port 21 link down инф. 135 Jan 3 05:21:58 2009 Port 21 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 136 Jan 3 05:21:57 2009 port 21 link down инф. 137 Jan 3 05:20:13 2009 port 16 link down инф. 138 Jan 3 05:18:19 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 139 Jan 3 05:18:16 2009 port 36 link down инф. 140 Jan 3 05:17:35 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 141 Jan 3 05:17:33 2009 port 36 link down инф. 142 Jan 3 02:49:17 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 143 Jan 3 02:49:14 2009 port 36 link down инф. 144 Jan 3 02:48:39 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 145 Jan 3 02:48:37 2009 port 36 link down инф. 146 Jan 2 23:46:58 2009 port 13 link down инф. 147 Jan 2 22:40:48 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 148 Jan 2 22:40:45 2009 port 36 link down инф. 149 Jan 2 22:40:11 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 150 Jan 2 22:40:09 2009 port 36 link down инф. 151 Jan 2 22:13:50 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 152 Jan 2 22:00:28 2009 Port 19 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 153 Jan 2 22:00:23 2009 port 19 link down инф. 154 Jan 2 21:59:55 2009 Port 19 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 155 Jan 2 21:59:53 2009 port 19 link down инф. 156 Jan 2 21:57:30 2009 Port 8 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 157 Jan 2 21:54:11 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 158 Jan 2 21:54:09 2009 port 11 link down инф. 159 Jan 2 21:53:54 2009 Port 11 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 160 Jan 2 21:49:41 2009 Port 28 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 161 Jan 2 21:49:39 2009 port 28 link down инф. 162 Jan 2 21:49:07 2009 Port 28 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 163 Jan 2 21:49:06 2009 port 28 link down инф. 164 Jan 2 21:46:00 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 165 Jan 2 21:02:22 2009 Port 22 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 166 Jan 2 21:02:19 2009 port 22 link down инф. 167 Jan 2 21:01:51 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 168 Jan 2 21:01:49 2009 port 22 link down инф. 169 Jan 2 20:59:10 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 170 Jan 2 20:58:33 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 171 Jan 2 20:58:31 2009 port 22 link down инф. 172 Jan 2 20:58:04 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 173 Jan 2 20:55:45 2009 Port 2 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 174 Jan 2 20:55:37 2009 Port 18 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 175 Jan 2 20:55:35 2009 port 18 link down инф. 176 Jan 2 20:55:18 2009 Port 18 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 177 Jan 2 20:55:15 2009 port 2 link down инф. 178 Jan 2 20:54:03 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 179 Jan 2 20:54:01 2009 port 32 link down инф. 180 Jan 2 20:53:57 2009 Port 22 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 181 Jan 2 20:53:55 2009 port 22 link down инф. 182 Jan 2 20:53:28 2009 Port 2 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 183 Jan 2 20:53:27 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 184 Jan 2 20:53:09 2009 Port 26 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 185 Jan 2 20:52:48 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 186 Jan 2 20:52:46 2009 port 32 link down инф. 187 Jan 2 20:52:42 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 188 Jan 2 20:52:41 2009 port 32 link down инф. 189 Jan 2 20:52:40 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 190 Jan 2 20:31:58 2009 Port 21 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 191 Jan 2 20:31:55 2009 port 21 link down инф. 192 Jan 2 20:31:26 2009 Port 21 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 193 Jan 2 20:31:24 2009 port 21 link down инф. 194 Jan 2 20:31:18 2009 Port 21 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 195 Jan 2 20:31:16 2009 port 21 link down инф. 196 Jan 2 20:30:43 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 197 Jan 2 20:30:41 2009 port 1 link down инф. 198 Jan 2 20:30:13 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 199 Jan 2 20:30:11 2009 port 1 link down инф. 200 Jan 2 20:30:09 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 201 Jan 2 20:30:08 2009 port 1 link down инф. 202 Jan 2 20:29:44 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 203 Jan 2 19:42:33 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 204 Jan 2 19:42:30 2009 port 36 link down инф. 205 Jan 2 19:10:33 2009 Port 10 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 206 Jan 2 18:42:54 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 207 Jan 2 11:41:48 2009 port 14 link down инф. 208 Jan 2 11:40:00 2009 port 11 link down инф. 209 Jan 2 11:34:13 2009 port 10 link down инф. 210 Jan 2 08:12:51 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 211 Jan 2 08:12:49 2009 port 11 link down инф. 212 Jan 2 08:12:34 2009 Port 11 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 213 Jan 2 07:52:23 2009 port 15 link down инф. 214 Jan 2 07:48:12 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 215 Jan 2 07:48:07 2009 port 15 link down инф. 216 Jan 2 07:47:49 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 217 Jan 2 06:45:37 2009 port 15 link down инф. 218 Jan 2 06:43:59 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 219 Jan 2 06:43:36 2009 port 15 link down инф. 220 Jan 2 06:43:17 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 221 Jan 2 06:43:12 2009 port 15 link down инф. 222 Jan 2 06:43:01 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 223 Jan 2 06:42:56 2009 port 15 link down инф. 224 Jan 2 06:42:36 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 225 Jan 2 06:41:22 2009 port 15 link down инф. 226 Jan 2 06:23:15 2009 port 2 link down инф. 227 Jan 2 06:21:57 2009 port 8 link down инф. 228 Jan 2 06:19:55 2009 Port 28 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 229 Jan 2 06:19:54 2009 port 28 link down инф. 230 Jan 2 06:19:00 2009 port 20 link down инф. 231 Jan 2 06:18:28 2009 port 18 link down инф. 232 Jan 2 06:17:53 2009 port 22 link down инф. 233 Jan 2 06:17:52 2009 port 32 link down инф. 234 Jan 2 06:17:50 2009 port 13 link down инф. 235 Jan 2 06:17:45 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 236 Jan 2 06:17:44 2009 port 26 link down инф. 237 Jan 2 06:17:42 2009 port 32 link down инф. 238 Jan 2 06:17:31 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 239 Jan 2 06:17:29 2009 port 22 link down инф. 240 Jan 2 06:16:21 2009 port 27 link down инф. 241 Jan 2 05:59:11 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 242 Jan 2 05:53:47 2009 port 1 link down инф. 243 Jan 2 05:52:36 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 244 Jan 2 05:52:34 2009 port 1 link down инф. 245 Jan 2 05:30:54 2009 port 11 link down инф. 246 Jan 2 05:25:02 2009 Port 21 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 247 Jan 2 05:25:00 2009 port 21 link down инф. 248 Jan 2 05:22:43 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 249 Jan 2 05:22:42 2009 port 36 link down инф. 250 Jan 2 05:20:04 2009 port 16 link down инф. 251 Jan 2 04:52:17 2009 Port 22 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 252 Jan 2 04:52:14 2009 port 22 link down инф. 253 Jan 2 04:51:48 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 254 Jan 2 04:51:46 2009 port 22 link down инф. 255 Jan 2 03:41:09 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 256 Jan 2 03:41:06 2009 port 36 link down инф. 257 Jan 2 03:40:31 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 258 Jan 2 03:40:29 2009 port 36 link down инф. 259 Jan 2 03:24:51 2009 Port 19 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 260 Jan 2 03:24:49 2009 port 19 link down инф. 261 Jan 2 02:45:40 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 262 Jan 2 01:52:53 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 263 Jan 2 01:52:03 2009 port 16 link down инф. 264 Jan 2 00:44:58 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 265 Jan 2 00:44:56 2009 port 32 link down инф. 266 Jan 2 00:43:42 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 267 Jan 2 00:43:40 2009 port 32 link down инф. 268 Jan 2 00:43:37 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 269 Jan 2 00:43:33 2009 port 32 link down инф. 270 Jan 2 00:43:25 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 271 Jan 2 00:43:22 2009 port 32 link down инф. 272 Jan 1 23:53:50 2009 port 13 link down инф. 273 Jan 1 22:42:49 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 274 Jan 1 22:12:57 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 275 Jan 1 22:12:55 2009 port 11 link down инф. 276 Jan 1 22:12:39 2009 Port 11 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 277 Jan 1 21:55:22 2009 Port 8 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 278 Jan 1 21:52:43 2009 Port 19 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 279 Jan 1 21:52:38 2009 port 19 link down инф. 280 Jan 1 21:52:10 2009 Port 19 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 281 Jan 1 21:52:08 2009 port 19 link down инф. 282 Jan 1 21:48:56 2009 Port 28 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 283 Jan 1 21:48:54 2009 port 28 link down инф. 284 Jan 1 21:48:22 2009 Port 28 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 285 Jan 1 21:48:20 2009 port 28 link down инф. 286 Jan 1 21:48:12 2009 Port 27 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 287 Jan 1 21:48:09 2009 port 27 link down инф. 288 Jan 1 21:47:36 2009 Port 27 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 289 Jan 1 21:13:27 2009 Port 2 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 290 Jan 1 21:01:45 2009 Port 22 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 291 Jan 1 21:01:43 2009 port 22 link down инф. 292 Jan 1 21:01:13 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 293 Jan 1 20:56:56 2009 Port 18 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 294 Jan 1 20:56:55 2009 port 18 link down инф. 295 Jan 1 20:56:13 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 296 Jan 1 20:56:10 2009 port 32 link down инф. 297 Jan 1 20:55:54 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 298 Jan 1 20:55:18 2009 Port 26 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 299 Jan 1 20:54:57 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 300 Jan 1 20:54:55 2009 port 32 link down инф. 301 Jan 1 20:54:51 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 302 Jan 1 20:54:50 2009 port 32 link down инф. 303 Jan 1 20:54:49 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 304 Jan 1 20:54:40 2009 Port 18 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 305 Jan 1 20:54:39 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 306 Jan 1 20:41:52 2009 Port 21 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 307 Jan 1 20:41:50 2009 port 21 link down инф. 308 Jan 1 20:41:21 2009 Port 21 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 309 Jan 1 20:41:18 2009 port 21 link down инф. 310 Jan 1 20:41:12 2009 Port 21 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 311 Jan 1 20:41:10 2009 port 21 link down инф. 312 Jan 1 20:31:58 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 313 Jan 1 20:31:57 2009 port 1 link down инф. 314 Jan 1 20:31:29 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 315 Jan 1 20:31:28 2009 port 1 link down инф. 316 Jan 1 20:31:26 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 317 Jan 1 20:31:24 2009 port 1 link down инф. 318 Jan 1 20:31:00 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 319 Jan 1 19:33:45 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 320 Jan 1 19:33:42 2009 port 36 link down инф. 321 Jan 1 19:06:23 2009 Port 10 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 322 Jan 1 18:41:49 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 323 Jan 1 11:44:45 2009 port 14 link down инф. 324 Jan 1 11:31:42 2009 port 11 link down инф. 325 Jan 1 11:29:59 2009 port 10 link down инф. 326 Jan 1 09:20:21 2009 Logout through Web( IP: 192.168.0.227 ) инф. 327 Jan 1 09:20:09 2009 Configuration saved to flash инф. 328 Jan 1 09:18:46 2009 Successful login through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.227 ) инф. 329 Jan 1 07:53:34 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 330 Jan 1 07:53:31 2009 port 11 link down инф. 331 Jan 1 07:53:14 2009 Port 11 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 332 Jan 1 07:42:49 2009 port 15 link down инф. 333 Jan 1 06:25:17 2009 port 11 link down инф. 334 Jan 1 06:23:40 2009 port 27 link down инф. 335 Jan 1 06:19:54 2009 Port 19 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 336 Jan 1 06:19:52 2009 port 19 link down инф. 337 Jan 1 06:19:28 2009 port 8 link down инф. 338 Jan 1 06:18:40 2009 port 18 link down инф. 339 Jan 1 06:18:29 2009 Port 28 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 340 Jan 1 06:18:28 2009 port 28 link down инф. 341 Jan 1 06:17:29 2009 port 22 link down инф. 342 Jan 1 06:17:19 2009 Port 22 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 343 Jan 1 06:17:17 2009 port 22 link down инф. 344 Jan 1 06:13:29 2009 port 13 link down инф. 345 Jan 1 06:09:20 2009 port 2 link down инф. 346 Jan 1 06:08:28 2009 port 26 link down инф. 347 Jan 1 06:08:15 2009 port 32 link down инф. 348 Jan 1 06:08:06 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 349 Jan 1 06:08:04 2009 port 32 link down инф. 350 Jan 1 06:04:53 2009 port 20 link down инф. 351 Jan 1 05:48:09 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 352 Jan 1 05:48:07 2009 port 36 link down инф. 353 Jan 1 05:44:42 2009 port 1 link down инф. 354 Jan 1 05:44:16 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 355 Jan 1 05:44:14 2009 port 1 link down инф. 356 Jan 1 05:38:48 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 357 Jan 1 05:38:45 2009 port 36 link down инф. 358 Jan 1 05:24:58 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 359 Jan 1 05:24:56 2009 port 36 link down инф. 360 Jan 1 05:23:45 2009 Port 21 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 361 Jan 1 05:23:44 2009 port 21 link down инф. 362 Jan 1 05:21:19 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 363 Jan 1 05:05:33 2009 port 16 link down инф. 364 Jan 1 04:29:22 2009 Port 15 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 365 Jan 1 04:22:14 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 366 Jan 1 04:22:12 2009 port 20 link down инф. 367 Jan 1 04:21:56 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 368 Jan 1 04:21:54 2009 port 20 link down инф. 369 Jan 1 04:20:55 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 370 Jan 1 04:20:53 2009 port 20 link down инф. 371 Jan 1 04:20:22 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 372 Jan 1 04:20:20 2009 port 20 link down инф. 373 Jan 1 02:57:07 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 374 Jan 1 02:57:05 2009 port 36 link down инф. 375 Jan 1 02:56:29 2009 Port 36 link up, 10Mbps FULL duplex инф. 376 Jan 1 02:56:28 2009 port 36 link down инф. 377 Jan 1 01:42:55 2009 port 13 link down инф. 378 Jan 1 01:08:03 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 379 Jan 1 01:08:01 2009 port 32 link down инф. 380 Jan 1 01:06:00 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 381 Jan 1 01:05:58 2009 port 32 link down инф. 382 Jan 1 01:05:54 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 383 Jan 1 01:05:52 2009 port 32 link down инф. 384 Jan 1 01:05:52 2009 Port 32 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 385 Jan 1 01:05:07 2009 port 32 link down инф. 386 Jan 1 00:23:37 2009 Logout through Web( IP: 192.168.0.229 ) инф. 387 Jan 1 00:23:27 2009 Configuration saved to flash инф. 388 Jan 1 00:23:20 2009 Successful login through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.229 ) инф. 389 Jan 1 00:18:15 2009 Logout through Web( IP: 192.168.0.227 ) инф. 390 Jan 1 00:18:15 2009 Web session timed out ( IP: 192.168.0.227 ) инф. 391 Jan 1 00:13:45 2009 Logout through Web( IP: 192.168.0.229 ) инф. 392 Jan 1 00:13:45 2009 Web session timed out ( IP: 192.168.0.229 ) инф. 393 Jan 1 00:13:06 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 394 Jan 1 00:13:06 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 395 Jan 1 00:12:53 2009 Port 19 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 396 Jan 1 00:12:52 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 397 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 31 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 398 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 399 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 35 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 400 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 27 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 401 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 33 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 402 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 29 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 403 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 28 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 404 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 21 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 405 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 8 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 406 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 22 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 407 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 408 Jan 1 00:12:51 2009 Port 7 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 409 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 2 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 410 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 26 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 411 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 10 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 412 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 413 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 34 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 414 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 38 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 415 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 30 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 416 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 17 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 417 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 418 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 23 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 419 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 18 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 420 Jan 1 00:12:50 2009 Port 6 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 421 Jan 1 00:12:49 2009 Port 12 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 422 Jan 1 00:12:49 2009 Port 3 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 423 Jan 1 00:12:49 2009 Port 1 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 424 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 38 link down инф. 425 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 36 link down инф. 426 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 35 link down инф. 427 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 34 link down инф. 428 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 33 link down инф. 429 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 33 link up, 1Gbps HALF duplex инф. 430 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 33 link down инф. 431 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 32 link down инф. 432 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 31 link down инф. 433 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 30 link down инф. 434 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 29 link down инф. 435 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 29 link up, 1Gbps HALF duplex инф. 436 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 29 link down инф. 437 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 28 link down инф. 438 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 27 link down инф. 439 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 26 link down инф. 440 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 23 link down инф. 441 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 23 link up, 100Mbps HALF duplex инф. 442 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 23 link down инф. 443 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 22 link down инф. 444 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 21 link down инф. 445 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 20 link down инф. 446 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 20 link up, 100Mbps HALF duplex инф. 447 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 20 link down инф. 448 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 19 link down инф. 449 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 18 link down инф. 450 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 18 link up, 100Mbps HALF duplex инф. 451 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 18 link down инф. 452 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 17 link down инф. 453 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 16 link down инф. 454 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 14 link down инф. 455 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 14 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф. 456 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 14 link down инф. 457 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 13 link down инф. 458 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 12 link down инф. 459 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 12 link up, 100Mbps HALF duplex инф. 460 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 12 link down инф. 461 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 11 link down инф. 462 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 10 link down инф. 463 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 Port 10 link up, 1Gbps HALF duplex инф. 464 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 10 link down инф. 465 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 8 link down инф. 466 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 7 link down инф. 467 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 6 link down инф. 468 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 3 link down инф. 469 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 2 link down инф. 470 Jan 1 00:12:48 2009 port 1 link down инф. 471 Jan 1 00:12:06 2009 Password was changed. инф. 472 Jan 1 00:11:45 2009 Successful login through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) инф. 473 Jan 1 00:11:41 2009 Login failed through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) предупреждение 474 Jan 1 00:11:33 2009 Login failed through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) предупреждение 475 Jan 1 00:10:45 2009 Logout through Web( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) инф. 476 Jan 1 00:10:45 2009 Web session timed out ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) инф. 477 Jan 1 00:05:34 2009 port 48 link down инф. 478 Jan 1 00:00:29 2009 Successful login through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) инф. 479 Jan 1 00:00:25 2009 Login failed through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) предупреждение 480 Jan 1 00:00:24 2009 Successful login through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY инф. 481 Jan 1 00:00:18 2009 Login failed through Web ( IP: 192.168.0.YYY ) предупреждение 482 Jan 1 00:00:17 2009 Port 13 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 483 Jan 1 00:00:17 2009 Port 16 link up, 100Mbps FULL duplex инф. 484 Jan 1 00:00:11 2009 Configuration saved to flash инф. 485 Jan 1 00:00:10 2009 System started up критичное 486 Jan 1 00:00:09 2009 Port 48 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 487 Jan 1 00:00:07 2009 port 48 link down инф. 488 Jan 1 00:00:05 2009 Port 48 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 489 Jan 1 00:00:05 2009 Port 36 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 490 Jan 1 00:00:05 2009 Port 32 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 491 Jan 1 00:00:05 2009 Port 29 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 492 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 7 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 493 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 2 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 494 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 11 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 495 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 21 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 496 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 22 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 497 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 27 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 498 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 8 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 499 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 28 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 500 Jan 1 00:00:04 2009 Port 33 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А в чем собственно проблема? Клиент взял да вык компьютер, бац линк даун.

Comment: Точно не выключал, компьютеры никто (если даже выключал, то включал через 2 секунды, что непросто) : 486 Jan 1 00:00:09 2009 Port 48 link up, 1Gbps FULL duplex инф. 487 Jan 1 00:00:07 2009 port 48 link down инф.К тому же, сегодня такого не наблюдается.

Comment: можно посмотреть ошибки на порту sh err ports <> может витуха виновна.Вообще когда комп ребутается линк падает на несколько сек.

Comment: на некоторых портах есть сообщения half duplex возможно трабла из за гигабитного линка.

Comment: если свитчу доступен интернет можно настроить ntp, время будит корректное

Comment: >sh err portsК сожалению, свич о такой не знает. Про ntp знаю, лень было :) А какая именно проблема может быть из-за гигабита? Вроде раньше нормально было.

Comment: качество кабеля, длинна, обжим коннектора.Попробуйте sh err потом табом добить.

Answer (score 0):

Выключил/включил это возможно. а как объяснить, например 17 Jan 5 22:45:27 2009 Port 11 link up, 10Mbps HALF duplex инф.Почему порты мерцают, обычно 10 халф это какой то косяк, либо провод, либо сетевая карта или просто порты дурят. Возможно что то с кабелем было, помеха сильная например .. работы никакие не проводились около кабелей?